# back-propagation of multiple top layers caffe

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, gradient-descent, differentiation

I am new to caffe. I have a question on multiple top layers for back-propagation, as the following show:
[image: multiple-top-layers-of-caffe]

My question is, what's the differentiation of x_i w.r.t x_{i-1} ?

Thanks in advance.

xiaox